# Android - Do I have to have WeakReference for inner class AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, weak-references

LEt's say I have an inner class AsyncTask in an Activity class. 
Do I have to have weakRefeernce in this AsyncTask?

Also, do I have to have weakReference for AsyncTask all the time?

Lastly, if I declare inner class AsyncTask as static, is it safe?

Answer (score 2):

Yes always declare your `Asynctask` static if it's an inner class or just create it's own class, try avoiding declaring as non-static inner class, as it creates memory leaks. [Read here for a more elaborate explanation why you should not do this](http://blog.andresteingress.com/2011/10/12/anonymous-inner-classes-in-android/)

You do not want to use [`WeakReference`](http://www.rallydev.com/community/engineering/java-references-strong-soft-weak-phantom) for an Asynctask since the garbage collector of android 2.3+ is very aggressive and will collect all weak refrences very fast. Also weak reference generally is NOT a good pattern for threads, its more for memory footprint heavy obects like bitmaps (but not anymore in android as said before).

From http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

> Starting from Android 2.3 (API Level 9) the garbage collector is more aggressive with collecting soft/weak references which makes them fairly ineffective.

Answer (score 1):

The `WeakReference` allows the `Activity` to be garbage collected, so you don't have a memory leak.

A null reference means that the `AsyncTask` cannot blindly try to update a user-interface that is no longer attached, which would throw exceptions (e.g. view not attached to window manager). Of course you have to check for null to avoid NPE. Hence it is a good practice to use `WeakReference` to handle the above mentioned situation.
And yes, it is perfectly safe to declare your inner class as `static`

```
WeakReference<Activity> weakActivity;
```

Somewhere in AsyncTask, probably either constructor or onPreExecute:

```
weakActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
```

In `onPostExecute`:

```
Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
if (activity != null) {
 // do your stuff with activity here
 }
```

from the activity in which you are starting the `AsyncTask`,pass `this` to the constructor. (I assume you write the assignment statement shown above in your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `WeakReference` for the right reason, then having an aggressive garbage collector shouldn't bother you.

`WeakReference` means that you're not interested in keeping that object in memory if no one else is strongly pointing to it.

For example, having an `AsyncTask` that is passed an `ImageView` to load an image into.

After the `AsyncTask` is done with it's work if no one is pointing to the image view with a strong reference, that means that the `ImageView` is no longer visible to the user and it's view  has been destroyed, so why would you possibly want to have a reference to a view that has been taken off screen.

So YES i believe that all of your references in an `AsyncTask` should be weak specially ones that is related to the UI "Views, Activity" stuff like that.

And YES you should have your inner classes declared as `static` as much as possible, so they don't have an implicit reference to its containing class, which will destroy what we have tried to do by using `WeakReference`

Comment: Isn't any object without a strong reference be able to be garbage collected? If you need to have a strong reference to a asynctask to not get automaically garabage collected in a weak reference, doens't that defeat the purpose? WeakRef usually is for e.g. caches, where it is ok to get a null, because you you just recreate the object. If the asynctask is null you have to recreate the whole task, and if you keep a strong ref anyway there is no point in weak references, or do I miss the point?

Comment: You completely misunderstood what i said, i didn't say to have a weak reference to the AsyncTask it self, i said to have a weak reference to the objects inside the async task, that's for start.
Seond, Threads in general, in java are kept and managed by the JVM, so if you start a thread or an asynctask and you don't have a refernce to it at all, it will still be in memory until it's done with it's work, then i will be garbage collected, but not before.

Comment: If the UI (activity) is finished, there will be no strong references to the imageView -> it will be collected no matter of weak or strong reference, so I do not get the advantage of the weak reference in that siutation. It only seems to add complexity without any gain.

Comment: Nope, if the activity is finished and you can a strong reference to the ImageView, the ImageView and the whole activity[if the ImageView is attached to the activity] will not be garbage colledted.